# Want Local Server with different PHP and MYSQL Versions

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, local, versions

I want to install some old Apps like vBulletin 2 etc. local and need different php Versions.
Best would be PHP 3 - 5.2 or even newer also mysql best 3 - 5.

Is there a solution for LOCAL use on Windows where i can switch between mysql and php version?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using IIS you can specify what version of php each `sites` uses.

*As for Apache2 you can only have one active at a time, guess im wrong ?... Other servers I don't know...*

You might run into a lot of trouble with multiple versions mysql on the same OS...

- Honestly I would setup a few VMs with minimal ubuntu for each scenarios...

Comment: "As for Apache2 you can only have one active" not true at  all

Comment: uh, guess I was miss-informed, please elaborate ? :D

Comment: is there no easy solution for having multiple versions of php and mysql? i want to use this on windows 7